# Laravel Logout Using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-7

I'm trying to write an AJAX script that will log me out of Laravel using a POST request:

```
$.ajax({
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: '/logout',

    success: function() {
        window.location.replace('https://portal.nchinc.com/?logout=timeout');
    }
});
```

The result is I just get redirected, the logout doesn't take effect. What am I doing wrong?

Note: The CSRF token is being set to avoid a 401 unauthorized HTTP response.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

It works

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry for mistake  change `$.ajaxSetup` instead of  `$.ajax`

Comment: Clear cache `php artisan cache:clear` and check again

Answer (score 0):

try like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/logout',
    data: {'_token' : "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
    success: function() {
        window.location.replace('https://portal.nchinc.com/?logout=timeout');
    }
});
```

You should not need the header to be set, but `_token` is required to avoid Csrf validation failure.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't log me out. It just redirects me. Still logged in.